# Is it possible to detect if Android webview's goBack() will load content from cache?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm having issue with Android webview's goBack() not sending custom request headers and cookies. I'm trying to fix this by reloading the whole page on goBack(), but it should be done only when goBack() is not going to load content from cache. Is there a way to programmatically detect that webview's goBack() is going to load content from cache or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the load isn't from the cache, then it will go through `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest`. Note that in the case of `goBack`, the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` will not be called, as it is *not* called for navigations started via the Java API calls.

Comment: Thanks. Technically we can detect if goBack is going to load from cache then, but using shouldInterceptRequest, I'm still unclear on how to achieve what I want. shouldInterceptRequest either returns null (which will make goBack() execute request itself without cookie/custom headers) or web response (which I don't want). Do you have suggestions on how I can i) use goBack default behavior if page is cached, and ii) call loadUrl and remove current page from history stack if page is not cached?

Comment: I'm in fact quite interested in checking your assertion that `goBack` doesn't send custom headers or cookies. This shouldn't be the case. Do you have a reduced example that reproduces this behavior? On what version of Android and WebView package does this happen? I mean, figuring out what is wrong with `goBack` should be the first priority, and thinking on how to work around this is secondary.

Comment: It definitely happens on some specific Android version (Jelly Bean or so, I can double check that with my team). I'm rewriting this component in Lollipop, and I did not see cookies/custom headers when inspecting in chrome's network tab so I thought I encouter the same issue. However I checked server-side and it does get cookies/custom headers from goBack()'s requests so it's all good now. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I've checked, JellyBean and older versions of WebView indeed do not inject custom headers on back / forward navigations. I guess, the only way to fix that is to completely implement your own resource loading via `shouldInterceptRequest`, but that's not trivial, and JellyBean phones shouldn't be considered seriously now.    And thanks for pointing out that the custom headers are missing in DevTools -- I'll check that out.